# Is it a good practice to execute PreparedStatement multiple times?

Tags: java, jdbc

I was wondering if it is a good practice to execute a PreparedStatement multiple times or we should reinitialize it each time.

For example:

```
while(i<100){
    PreparedStatement ptsmt = con.preparedStatement("INSERT into counts (counter) values (?)"); 
    ptsmt.setInt(1,i);
    ptsmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Is worse or better than ?

```
PreparedStatement ptsmt = con.preparedStatement("INSERT into counts (counter) values (?)"); 
while(i<100){
    ptsmt.setInt(1,i);
    ptsmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: That is the whole point of preparedStatements. And 2nd option is the proper way to go.

Answer (score 4):

The second code is recomended. The `PreparedStatement` is intended to be reused. Read what the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) says:

> A SQL statement is precompiled and stored in a `PreparedStatement` object. This object can then be used to efficiently execute this statement multiple times.

Remember to always call [`clearParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#clearParameters()) before reusing it:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.preparedStatement(
        "INSERT INTO counts (counter) VALUES (?)"); 
while (i < 100) {
    pstmt.clearParameters();
    pstmt.setInt(1, ++i);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Calling `clearParameters` is not really necessary if you are going to set all parameter values again.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer the second one.  The whole point is to create it once and reuse it.

Comment: But is it wise to use it that way, or can we prefer updating in a batch?

Comment: @BatScream That question doesn't make sense. It's not a question of one or the other. Updating with a batch also requires you to re-use the statement.

Comment: @EJP, Thank you for responding. Actually i had misunderstood the question.